# How do I disable driver signing enforcement on Windows Server 2008 R2 x64?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, 64-bit, drivers

I'm running Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 and I have a driver that isn't signed so the Device Manager displays the following message:

"Windows cannot verify the digital signature for the drivers required for this device. A recent hardware or software change might have installed a file that is signed incorrectly or damaged, or that might be malicious software from an unknown source. (Code 52)"

I know that I can disable driver signing enforcement per-boot by using F8 but I'd like something more permanent, or I'd like a way to sign this driver myself and allow Windows to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has some information on [Signing Drivers during Development and Test (Windows Vista and Later)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff552275.aspx). Self-signing the driver would be preferred to disabling signature verification globally.

Answer (score 0):

I had to upgrade an N54L BCM,

Driver Signature Enforcement Overrider 1.3b

http://www.ngohq.com/?page=Files&go=giveme&dwn_id=826